# SQl how to check that a column record contain a part of anothor column record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a request where I need to check if all records of a column `cost_code` contain a string composed of column `invoices` records 
and one character of type number.

How can I achieve this task?

I tried it with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Deal WHERE cost_code LIKE ('invoice%');
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CONCAT()` can be used with `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM Deal WHERE cost_code LIKE CONCAT(invoices, '%');
```

If `cost_code` is `ABCD1234` & `invoices` is `1234`, Then you can use query as:

```
SELECT * FROM Deal WHERE cost_code LIKE 
CONCAT( SUBSTRING( invoices, 5, length(invoices) -4), '%');
```

Comment: `cast( ... as unsigned)` is invalid for Oracle. And using those dreaded backticks in an identifier as well

Comment: Sorry, I donot have Oracle to work with. If there is no `CAST()`, it can be remove from query.

Comment: The solution with `substr ` worked fine with little tunning : 

`SELECT * FROM Deal WHERE cost_code LIKE substr(invoice, 1, 9);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
where not regexp_like(cost_code, '^invoice[0-9]$')
```